# Parsing XML content with absent elements in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing, sql-server-2012

I need to parse XML below into table of transactions for the customers for each day. The XML file is coming from external service which is not controlled by me.

The problem is when a customer doesn't have a transaction for the day, I am not able to view it in my table. How do I get to see that customer had zero transactions?

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<root>
    <customers>
        <customer id="777">
          <orders>
            <order currency="USD" id="888" date="2014-06-18">
              <transactions>
                <transaction id="998">
                  <date>2014-08-01</date>
                  <itemid>10001</itemid>
                  <amount>745.96</amount>
                </transaction>
              </transactions>
            </order>
          </orders>
    </customer>
    <customer id="778">
      <orders>
        <order id="999" />
      </orders>
    </customer>
  </customers>
</root>'
```

My transformation query is like this:

```
select
newid()                                                 ID,
    ltrim(rtrim(B.C.value('@id', 'nvarchar(50)')))          CUSTOMER_ID,
    ltrim(rtrim(K.C.value('@id', 'nvarchar(450)')))         ACCOUNT_ID,
    ltrim(rtrim(K.C.value('@date', 'datetime')))            DATE_PLACED,
    ltrim(rtrim(K.C.value('@currency', 'nvarchar(50)')))    CURRENCY,
    ltrim(rtrim(T.C.value('@id', 'nvarchar(50)')))          TRANSACTION_ID,
    ltrim(rtrim(T.C.value('date[1]', 'datetime')))          TRANSACTION_DATE,
    ltrim(rtrim(T.C.value('itemid[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')))    TRANSACTION_ITEMID,
    ltrim(rtrim(T.C.value('amount[1]', 'money')))   TRANSACTION_BANK_CODE
from 
@xml.nodes('/root/customers/customer') as B(C)
outer apply B.C.nodes('/root/customers/customer/orders/order') as K(C)
outer apply K.C.nodes('/root/customers/customer/orders/order/transactions/transaction') as T(C)

where 
    ltrim(rtrim(b.c.value('@id', 'nvarchar(50)'))) = ltrim(rtrim(k.c.value('../../@id', 'nvarchar(50)')))
and 
(
    (
        t.c.value('../../@id','nvarchar(50)') is not null 
        and 
        ltrim(rtrim(k.c.value('@id','nvarchar(50)'))) = ltrim(rtrim(t.c.value('../../@id','nvarchar(50)')))
    ) 
    or (ltrim(rtrim(t.c.value('../../@id','nvarchar(50)'))) is null)
)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do the cross apply against the full xpath from root. Begin with where you are instead and remove the where clause.

```sql
select newid() as ID,
       B.C.value('@id', 'nvarchar(50)') as CUSTOMER_ID,
       K.C.value('@id', 'varchar(50)') as ACCOUNT_ID,
       T.C.value('@id', 'nvarchar(50)') as TRANSACTION_ID
from @xml.nodes('/root/customers/customer') as B(C)
  outer apply B.C.nodes('orders/order') as K(C)
  outer apply K.C.nodes('transactions/transaction') as T(C)
```

Result

```
ID                                   CUSTOMER_ID ACCOUNT_ID TRANSACTION_ID
------------------------------------ ----------- ---------- --------------
767FCA17-578A-495E-9EFA-75E3509B2BD2 777         888        998
59965290-EB7C-429B-AA5F-97EED0EB35BD 778         999        NULL
```

Comment: "Begin with where you are" helped, I have tried it with '/orders/order' and since it didn't work, had abandoned that idea. Now removed the first backward slash and it worked! Thanks!